# Cypress test failing due to error in Application Code

Tags: cypress

Cypress tests are failing due to application code error and not my code error. I have tried to bypass the error by using below code, but still it does not work. I can see similar bug is open in Github by Cypress team but someone can please provide a workaround, if any?

```
on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {

  return false
})
```

Comment: Not sure if you're referring to this issue or another one, but I've seen they've described some workaround in this one couple of weeks ago. Maybe try it out if you haven't yet:

https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/987

Comment: I am following the same thread and the workaround provided in the thread is not working in my case

Answer (score 3):

From https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/987:

> [Cypress doesn't] have a handler on `top.onerror`, only on the spec iframe and app iframe, and some errors will bubble straight to top.

As a workaround, you can add this to the top of your spec file or `support/index.js`:

```js
// ignore uncaught exceptions
Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err) => {
  return false
})

// patch Cypress top.onerror
Object.defineProperty(top, 'onerror', {
  value: window.onerror,
})
```

Comment: We also can add `if (err.message.includes('Expected error')) { return false }` to be more assertive